# Two divs side by side, without container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have to inline two divs side by side. The thing is, I can't edit HTML and they don't have a container. To make things even more complicated, the first div needs to be wider than the second one. And I have no idea how to do this **and** make it responsive.

This is what I have so far. But it's not responsive. To make it so, I'd have to edit it with @media and I'm really trying to avoid that. Is there a way I could make this cleaner? A way I could use flex maybe, without a container? And make it responsive too, without having it meshed together on smaller devices?

```css
.one,
.two {
  float: left;
}

.one {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.two {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">content goes here</div>
<div class="two">content goes here</div>
```

**EDIT:** This is what the outline of my code looks like, with a container. Just to get you guys more information about the issue. Div with a class section-one has 5 items inside, and they need to stay inlined and responsive when the window is resized, so I don't want to mess up the code I currently have because it behaves well on smaller screens.

```css
.container {}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.section-one {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section-left {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 66.66%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.section-right {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
    <p>Morbi posuere mi condimentum dui suscipit vulputate. Donec lectus diam.</p>
  </div>
  <!--- /.heading -->
  <div class="section-one">
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-one -->
  <div class="section-left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu sodales est. Nullam cursus id nibh mattis porta. Cras aliquet eros urna, quis imperdiet tortor placerat sed.
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-left -->
  <div class="section-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu sodales est. Nullam cursus id nibh mattis porta. Cras aliquet eros urna, quis imperdiet tortor placerat sed.
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-right -->
</div>
```

Comment: There must be parent element of some kind even if it's just the `<body>`. I suspect there's more to this story.

Comment: They're in a container, but they are not alone in there. So I will mess it all up if I apply display: flex and flex-direction to that.

Comment: If you have other content around, you need to make sure they see and clear the floatting boxes . However , they will need to be side by side in the code to avoid others to fill in between. Mind also to reset margin and box-sizing so you do have all together <100% and not 100% + padding + border + margin ;)

Comment: Give us more code that really shows your issue (what is there around, what are other styling (border,margins ? ... ) You can use lorem ipsum text and image . @media is not so bad nor difficult to use ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr Hey, thanks for your comment! I've edited the question and added the outline of the code. Can you please take a look and let me know your opinion? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact you already use Flexbox, I suggest you do it for this too, like this.

*If you don't want the `container`, just drop its markup and move its CSS properties to the `body`*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uuzrwu1k/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;                  /*  added  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;                /*  added  */
}

.heading {
  flex: 0 0 100%;                 /*  added, behaves like a block  */
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.section-one {
  flex: 0 0 100%;                 /*  added, behaves like a block  */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section-left {
  flex: 1 0 66.666%;              /*  added, behaves like an inline-block but fill when on single line  */
  min-width: 400px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;         /*  added, make padding be included in set width  */
  border: 1px dotted gray;        /*  demo purpose  */
}

.section-right {
  flex: 1 0 33.333%;              /*  added, behaves like an inline-block but fill when on single line  */
  min-width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;         /*  added, make border be included in set width  */      
  border: 1px dotted gray;        /*  demo purpose  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
    <p>Morbi posuere mi condimentum dui suscipit vulputate. Donec lectus diam.</p>
  </div>
  <!--- /.heading -->
  <div class="section-one">
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-one -->
  <div class="section-left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu sodales est. Nullam cursus id nibh mattis porta. Cras aliquet eros urna, quis imperdiet tortor placerat sed.
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-left -->
  <div class="section-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu sodales est. Nullam cursus id nibh mattis porta. Cras aliquet eros urna, quis imperdiet tortor placerat sed.
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-right -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is amazing and very simple! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Retros Thanks...also made an update so the left/right on smaller screen wraps and fills full width

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CSS calc() function`  along-with `display:inline-block` instead of `float` to align both divs responsively without making use of `media query`.

But as both divs are display as `inline-block` and when using inline-block it adds `white-space` around it's block, to remove that I have used `font-size:0` in `body` tag, so on remaining block in your design you have to assign `font-size` manually or else text won't be visible.

```css
body{
  font-size:0;
  margin:0;
}
.one{
  display:inline-block;
  background:pink;
  width:calc(100vw - 40vw);
  font-size:16px;
}
.two{
  display:inline-block;
  background:pink;
  width:calc(100vw - 60vw);
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
<div class="one">content goes here</div>
<div class="two">content goes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a media query anyway to make your divs on top of each other on small devices, especially if you have text content. The max-width I'm giving to you is just an example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .one,
    .two {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I would gladly suggest you the flex-box property, but if you don't got a container and can't modify the HTML, this will be complicated.
Here's the link anyway : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

With flexbox, you just have to give the property to your container :

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Then you can choose the way you want to sort your elements :

```
.container {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Again this is an example, check the link i gave you for further informations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to include `padding` and `border` into width calculation.

> The CSS **`box-sizing`** property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate width and height of the elements.

A [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) will help to pile them when boxes become too small.

> **Media queries** are useful when you want to apply CSS styles depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen), specific characteristics (such as the width of the browser viewport), or environment (such as ambient light conditions). With the huge variety of internet-connected devices available today, media queries are a vital tool for building websites and apps that are robust enough to work on whatever hardware your users have.

example

```css
.container {}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.section-one {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.section-left {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 66.66%;
  /*margin-top: 80px; remove */
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.section-right {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* updates */

  .section-left,
  .section-right {
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }

@media all and (max-width : 599px) {
  .section-left,
  .section-right {
    width:100%;
    padding:1em;
  }
}

/* let's see them */
div {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
    <p>Morbi posuere mi condimentum dui suscipit vulputate. Donec lectus diam.</p>
  </div>
  <!--- /.heading -->
  <div class="section-one">
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
    <div class="item">Praesent eu elementum.</div>
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-one -->
  <div class="section-left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu sodales est. Nullam cursus id nibh mattis porta. Cras aliquet eros urna, quis imperdiet tortor placerat sed.
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-left -->
  <div class="section-right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu sodales est. Nullam cursus id nibh mattis porta. Cras aliquet eros urna, quis imperdiet tortor placerat sed.
  </div>
  <!--- /.section-right -->
</div>
```